# C# Class Can't Use for Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone-8, azure-storage

I am new to the windows azure world, I am trying to send an item to the SQL DB and track it by a specific "usrID" to then hopefully update it.

Right now I also have a class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "usrID")]
    public string usrID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "complete")]
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

To save/insert Data I use:

```
    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var todoItem = new Item { usrID = "helloworld", url = Input.Text };
        InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
    }
```

When I am trying to update, I am using this:

```
    private void btns_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Item item;
        item = new Item();
        item.url = "hello";
        UpdateItem(item);
    }
```

*** Trying to do this will not work. It also wont let me do Item item = new Item();

The update function is:

```
    private async void UpdateItem(Item item)
    {
        await todoTable.UpdateAsync(item);
        items.Remove(item);
    }
```

So, what I am trying to do is, the last/only item inserted by "usrID" to get that data and show it. But also if something changes, I want that one specific insert from "usrID" that includes url to be updated (opposed from deleted entirely).

Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? Please post exception or compiler message details. BTW, I recommend you change `UpdateItem` to be `async Task`, not `async void`.

Comment: When I mean it won't work, I mean everytime I hit that button, I get: +  [System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException] {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at todotester.MainPage.<InsertTodoItem>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)

Comment: Your exception is happening inside `InsertTodoItem`. Could you post the source for that method?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Item> items = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>().OrderBy(item => item.usrID).ToListAsync();

int mas = items.Count();

await Table.UpdateAsync(new Item {Id = mas, usrID = "helloworld", url = "itworked" });
```